# Can't use SQLite Entity Framework as DataGridView DataSource

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite, datasource

I've built an Entity Framework Model from a simple SQLite database using the 'Entity Data Model Wizard'

This works fine and I've been programming aginst it for a while.

However, I've just tried to use this SQLite entity framework model as a DataSource for a DataGridView and it cannot see it as a datasource. Everything suggests that this should be possible. Creating a DataSet from the same database works and the DataGridView can use this as a datasource.

I would prefer to use the entity framework but can't understand why it's not seeing it as a valid datasource.

Please help!

As requested here is the app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
</DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
  <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
    <listeners>
      <add name="FileLog" />
      <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
      <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<switches>
  <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
</switches>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" initializeData="FileLogWriter" />
  <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
  <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
</sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="simpleEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GEM.Classes.test1.csdl|res://*/GEM.Classes.test1.ssdl|res://*/GEM.Classes.test1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data source=E:\simple.db3&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

As a test I've used a very simple database:

```
CREATE TABLE SETTINGS (
KEY VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
VALUE VARCHAR(255)  NULL DEFAULT NULL);
```

Comment: Can it be that you did not add corresponding entries to your web.config file?

Comment: PLease show relevant pieces of code. A DGV can accept a DbSet (or ObjectSet) as data source, so something else must be wrong.

Comment: I've added the app.config file and sql as requested.

Comment: Gert - I'm trying to set the data source using the properties dialog in the UI designer. If it's set here it allows me to configure the DGV more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to ditch EF and go with a DataSet which seems to work great.